# Example numbering and referencing

Tags: hyperref

I am quite new to LateX and I need help with my bachelor's thesis. I am writing a mathematical thesis with many examples in it and I need to label and reference my examples.

I'll give u an example what exactly do I need:

```
\chapter{chapter_name}
some text
\section{section_name}
some text
%dunno how to get this number and reference here
\textbf{Example chapter_number.section_number.example_number:} \\
$Here is some mothematical example$\\
\\
...
%dont know how to reference the example
In example chapter_number.section_number.example_number we can find ...
```

I tried the \label and \ref, but it was just referencing the sections and not the example.

Comment: Hi and welcome, package `amsthm` provides all you need with `newtheorem`. There are other theorem related packages as well.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx. It is hard to comment on a fragment we can not run, but generally you should avoid any use of `\\ ` outside tables, and similarly `\textbf` looks wrong. If it is just a font change you can not reference it, with `\ref` and `\label` It should probably be something like `\begin{example}\label{myex}`.....  in `\ref{myex}` but it needs a proper test example document to be sure what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `example` as a theorem structure. You can easily do what you want with the `ntheorem` package: what you ask is the  `break` style in this package. I added the `cleveref` package for a more powerful management of cross references (if, for  instance some of your examples later become remarks, you won't to go a-chasing all occurrences of the word ‘example’ to replace some of them with ‘remark’):

```
\documentclass{report}%]

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath, framed]{ntheorem}%
\usepackage{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\mdseries}
\theoremseparator{\smallskip }

\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]

\begin{document}

\chapter{An Interesting Chapter}

\section{A First Section}

\begin{example}[Title] \label{ex-a}
This is the first example. The counter will be reset at each section.
\end{example}

\begin{example}[Title the Second]\label{ex-b}
This is the second example of the first section. It’s the continuation and development of \cref {ex-a}.
\end{example}

\section{Another Section}

\begin{example}[Title title]\label{ex-c}
This is the first example of the second section, referring to \cref{ex-b}. The counter was reset.
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The newtheorem did exactly what I needed.
First I createt the theorem:

```
\newtheorem{mydef}{Example}[section]
```

Then my example would look like this

```
\begin{mydef}
\label{example:math}
$Mathematical examlpe$
\end{mydef}

In example \ref{example:math} we can find ...
```